# django permissions not being respected

Tags: django, django-models, django-permissions

I am trying to show a button if the logged in user has the right permissions.

The code in the template:

```
  {% if perms.django_apo_training.can_add %}
   <a href="{% url 'training:trainee_add' %}">     
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Trainee</button>    
   </a>
   {% endif %}
```

I can print to the webpage to debug what the permissions the user has:

```
  <p> {{ perms.django_apo_training }} </p>
```

It shows:

```
{'training.view_trainee', 'training.add_trainee', 'training.delete_trainee', 'training.change_trainee'}
```

but

```
perms.django_apo_training.can_add
```

always returns false, not sure what what I am missing?

Even double checked in the admin console:

[image]

(if I grant super user status to the the user in question, then the if statement works and returns true?)

Here is the model for the trainee stuff

```
# Create your models here.
class Trainee(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    contact_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    trained_date = models.DateField('date trained')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['institution']

    def __str__(self):
        return "Trainee: " + str(self.first_name) + " " + str(self.last_name) + "   " + str(self.institution)
```

Secondly... even once this works, how do I make sure that only those with that permission and logged in can get to (it is a lot more than an @login required decorator)

```
http://localhost:8000/training/add/
```

Lastly :   I have also created model to extend the user model using the one-to-one model:

```
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Inside this APOUser model I call it, I have other fields that I would *love* to key off of for these permissions (specifically what is contained in the `on_site_status`), is there some set way or example/recipe of how one might do that?
(the full model is here)

```
class APOUser(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    institution =  models.ForeignKey("mainpage.Institution", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    on_site_status = models.ForeignKey("mainpage.SiteStatus", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,  null=True)
    refer_to_as = models.TextField(max_length = 30, blank=True, null=True) #if the above is custom
    room_preference  = models.ForeignKey("housing.Room", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,  null=True)
```

Comment: `perms.django_apo_training.add_apouser` - superuser will return true for every permission even if the permission does not exist.

Comment: @bdoubleu I see on superuser.  I might have to edit my question, the lastly portion was related closely to 'once I figure out the first two' but it is seperate from just trying to get the button to show up from the training.can_add.  I will add that model as well.

Comment: It seems to me, that you should check it with: `if perms.training.can_add`

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov I agree as well, but a   <p> {{ perms.training.can_add }} </p>shows false too.

Comment: From your code, your permission for adding is actually called 'training.add_trainee'. So, the check should look like: `if perms.training.add_trainee`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard permissions created follow the format `<app_label>.view_<model_name>`. So in the `product` app with the following models a total of 8 permissions will be automatically created.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...

class Product(models.Model):
    ...

# permissions for the Category model
'product.view_category'
'product.add_category'
'product.change_category'
'product.delete_category'

# permissions for the Product model
'product.view_product'
'product.add_product'
'product.change_product'
'product.delete_product'
```

In your example `perms.django_apo_training.can_add` will always return `False` because there is no permission `can_add` - unless you have a model called `Add` and have created a custom permission. The correct pattern should be `perms.training.add_training`.

It's also important to note that checking the permissions for a superuser will always return `True` even if the permission does not exist.

For protected views with permissions and custom user fields you can subclass `UserPassesTestMixin`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

def permissions_check(user):
    approved_profile_status = ['ADMIN', 'PURCHASER']
    permission = 'training.add_trainee'

    is_approved = user.profile.on_site_status in approved_profile_status
    has_perm = user.has_perm(permission)
    return is_approved or has_perm


class PermissionsMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self):
        return permissions_check(self.request.user)


class TraineeListView(PermissionsMixin, ListView):
    ...
```